# Read CheckBox Values in ASP.Net from a SQL db?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a table of CheckBoxes that are inserted into a SQL db as '1' and '0'. However, I would like to retrieve those values again with a load event, but I'm not able to get them. This is my code:

```
    private void getAuditChecklist()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = null;
    string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    string queryString = @"SELECT Mount, Braker, Access, Conn_Net, Log_Book, Pictures, Floor, Cb_Lenght, Channel FROM AUDITOR_CHECKLIST " +
        "WHERE SITE_ID = @SiteID";        

    using (SqlConnection connection =
               new SqlConnection(conn))
    {
        SqlCommand command =
            new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString);
        cmd.Connection = connection;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SiteID", //the name of the parameter to map
              System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, //SqlDbType value
              20, //The width of the parameter
              "SITE_ID")); //The name of the column source
        //Fill the parameter with the value retrieved
        //from the text field
        cmd.Parameters["@SiteID"].Value = foo.Site_ID;

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
   {                    
   CheckBox1.Checked = (reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Mount")));
   CheckBox2.Checked = (reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Braker")));
   CheckBox3.Checked = (reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Access")));
   CheckBox4.Checked = (reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Conn_Net")));
   CheckBox5.Checked = (reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Log_Book")));
   CheckBox6.Checked = (reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Pictures")));
   CheckBox8.Checked = (reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Floor")));
   CheckBox9.Checked = (reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Cb_lenght")));
   CheckBox10.Checked = (reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Channel")));
   } 
   reader.Close();
    }        
}
```

What am I missing to get the checkmark from the sql db? Below is how insert into sql:

```
    private void SaveAuditChecklist()
{
    if (auditChecklist != null)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        string queryString = @"INSERT INTO AUDITOR_CHECKLIST VALUES(" +
            "@SiteID, @Mount, @Braker, @Access, @ConnNet, @LogBook, @Pictures, @Floor, @CbLenght, @Channel) ";

        using (SqlConnection connection =
                   new SqlConnection(conn))
        {
            SqlCommand command =
                new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
            connection.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString);
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(
                "@SiteID",                        //the name of the parameter to map
                System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar,   //SqlDbType value
                20,                               //The width of the parameter
                "Site_ID"));                      //The name of the column source

            //Fill the parameter with the value retrieved
            //from the text field
            cmd.Parameters["@SiteID"].Value = foo.Site_ID;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Mount", SqlDbType.Bit));
            cmd.Parameters["@Mount"].Value = CheckBox1.Checked;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Braker", SqlDbType.Bit));
            cmd.Parameters["@Braker"].Value = CheckBox2.Checked;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Access", SqlDbType.Bit));
            cmd.Parameters["@Access"].Value = CheckBox3.Checked;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ConnNet", SqlDbType.Bit));
            cmd.Parameters["@ConnNet"].Value = CheckBox4.Checked;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LogBook", SqlDbType.Bit));
            cmd.Parameters["@LogBook"].Value = CheckBox5.Checked;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Pictures", SqlDbType.Bit));
            cmd.Parameters["@Pictures"].Value = CheckBox6.Checked;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Floor", SqlDbType.Bit));
            cmd.Parameters["@Floor"].Value = CheckBox8.Checked;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CbLenght", SqlDbType.Bit));
            cmd.Parameters["@CbLenght"].Value = CheckBox9.Checked;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Channel", SqlDbType.Bit));
            cmd.Parameters["@Channel"].Value = CheckBox10.Checked;
            cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't read back the values for the other checkbox. How do you suppose to set the other checkboxes ?

Comment: Well, for saving on Text in this example, I just did the first CheckBox. I assume that, the code(reader) on the next checkBoxes is going to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Finally got the reader they way it should work to get the checkmark values. I edited my question with the working code; however, below is what I added or changed for the reader:

```
while (reader.Read())
{                    
CheckBox1.Checked = (reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Mount")));
CheckBox2.Checked = (reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Braker")));
CheckBox3.Checked = (reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Access")));
CheckBox4.Checked = (reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Conn_Net")));
CheckBox5.Checked = (reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Log_Book")));
CheckBox6.Checked = (reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Pictures")));
CheckBox8.Checked = (reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Floor")));
CheckBox9.Checked = (reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Cb_lenght")));
CheckBox10.Checked = (reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Channel")));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Booleans are stored as 1 or 0 in Sql Database, but the datareader do the conversion for you. Instead use:

```
var myBool = reader.GetBoolean(i);
```

Then just assign the value to the control's value property.

Comment: Thanks, I changed to GetBoolean(i)... but I didn't get which control value property or where to assign it. Could you elaborate more, please.

Comment: var myBool = reader.GetBoolean(i);
    mycheckBox.IsChecked = myBool;

Comment: I did that, and now I get the following error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Please help!

Comment: Well, I'm just writing partial code. I suppose you know how to obtain a reference to your checkbox and how to manage null values in a datareader. Try with:

var myBool = reader.GetBoolean(i) != null ? reader.GetBoolean(i) : false;

Another choice is to declare myBool as nullable.

bool? myBool;

Comment: Thanks, I did the reference before the reader like: 
"if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)" however, when I run the app the checkbox is empty, and no value is returned.

Comment: Maybe you're receiving a null value from ddbb. 
Also, you can write  (CheckBox1.Checked) instead of  (CheckBox1.Checked == true). They are the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oscar, I tried everything to read the checkbox values with no luck. it's weird that I could read other values like text, but I'm having a hard time with boolean values.